# Parsing Instant using OpenCsv

Tags: java, java-time, opencsv, datetime-parsing, java.time.instant

I am trying to parse Instant from a CSV using OpenCsv this way:

```
@CsvDate("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
@CsvBindByName(column = "date")
private Instant date;
```

I know that OpenCsv is supposed to support `java.time`.

But when trying to use it I am getting the following exception:

> Error parsing CSV line: 8.

...

> Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2022-04-21 00:00:00' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain Instant from TemporalAccessor: {HourOfAmPm=0, MicroOfSecond=0, NanoOfSecond=0, MilliOfSecond=0, MinuteOfHour=0, SecondOfMinute=0},ISO resolved to 2022-04-21 of type java.time.format.Parsed

...

> Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain Instant from TemporalAccessor: {HourOfAmPm=0, MicroOfSecond=0, NanoOfSecond=0, MilliOfSecond=0, MinuteOfHour=0, SecondOfMinute=0},ISO resolved to 2022-04-21 of type java.time.format.Parsed

...

> Caused by: java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: InstantSeconds

What comes from my investigation, is that the root cause is the lack of a time zone, but my question is how do I specify the time zone using the annotation only?

Comment: An `Instant` is a point in time independent of time zone and therefore neither defines year, month, day-of-month. hour, minute nor second. So trying to parse it using a format holding those elements does not make sense, at least not if you don’t specify the time zone or offset from UTC.

Comment: That is a good point, but as I was saying in the question I understand that the issue here is the lack of a time zone. So, you can say that my question is more about - is it possible to specify the time zone in `OpenCsv` + `@CsvDate`. Also, I'd assume that it would get a default UTC time zone if not supplied (though it seems like it isn't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [DateTimeFormatter](https://In%20every%20case%20it%20should%20be%20%60HH%60%20for%2024%20hours%20time%20i.o.%20%60hh%60%20for%2012%20hours%20time.). It should be `HH` for 24 hours time (0-23) i.o. `hh` for 12 hours time (1-12). The error is caused by hour "00". Fortunately, otherwise you would have only the first half of the day.

See h, k, H and K.

The class `Instant` does not use units like seconds, is more a long internally. Use `LocalDateTime` for your format.

Comment: I've changed it to HH, but still having the same error

Comment: Would you try it with `private LocalDateTime date;` i.o. `Instant`?

Comment: This one did the trick, I wonder why Instant does not work...
Thx a lot!!

Comment: Extended the answer. Already thought that Instant is a too amorph class. The same as adding time HH:mm for a LocalDate (no time).

Answer (score 1):

> What comes from my investigation, is that the root cause is the lack of a time zone, but my question is how do I specify the time zone using the annotation only?

I haven't find a way to change the timezone of the `DateTimeFormatter` used by OpenCSV. You could, in theory, use `@CsvCustomBindByName` and provide a [custom converter](https://opencsv.sourceforge.net/index.html#custom_converters) in which you can use your own `DateTimeFormatter` with the timezone you want.

However, if you also control how your CSV is generated, you can simply use the following datetime patterns to make it work with `Instant`:

```
@CsvBindByName(column = "date")
@CsvDate(
        value = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX",
        writeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'",
        writeFormatEqualsReadFormat = false)
private Instant date;
```

`value` is the pattern used when reading a bean from a CSV file. `X` is a pattern letter which will corresponds to the zone offset, i.e. when reading the 'Z' character, it will assume the time to be in UTC+00:00. See [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

When writing a bean to a CSV file, the `writeFormat` pattern will be used and needs to be different, you need to print the 'Z' char manually at the end, hence the escaped `'Z'`. The reason is that internally OpenCSV does the following when writing an `Instant`:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant((Instant) value, ZoneId.of("UTC"));
return writeDtf.format(ldt);
```

`LocalDateTime` does not have a timezone, so the `X` cannot be used. Arguably, they could instead do the following:

```
return writeDtf.withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(value);
```

Which would then allow us to use the `X`. They could also do the same when parsing a date to an `Instant`, in order to be consistent.